# Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-resolver` imported from `appName/resolver'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using

```
ember-cli: 3.4.3 ,
node js:10.16.3,
ember-resolver: 5.2.1
```

ember-serve work perfectly and give

```
Build successful (25929ms) – Serving on http://localhost:4232/
```

but on browser console the following error comes and unable to process further

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-resolver` imported from `appName/resolver'
```

I tried deleting package-lock.json ,node-modules, clearing cache & reinstalling still the same

Can any one help on this please

Comment: Is `appName` the real application name?

Comment: No the real application name is different , its just for reference

Comment: What did you change in the application when it started breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue with one dependency in package.json
"ember-light-table": "2.0.0-beta.4"
It seems this version of ember table is not compatible with other ember dependencies
reverted it to "ember-light-table": "2.0.0-beta.3",
now it is working fine

Answer (score -1):

upgrade ember-source to @3.17.1 or higher